# No targets . Stop

Tags: makefile, target

This is my direcctoriy
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg6t0.png)

What i dont know is why I get the message

> no targets.stop

```
CFLAGS := -g -std=c++11# -Wall
LIB := -L lib -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt

# ALL SERVER %.o
/build/server/%.o: /src/server.cpp /lib/server/%.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) /src/server.cpp /lib/server/%.cpp -o -c $@ $^
```

Comment: how do you run `make`?

Comment: Because `/` isn't the current directory. It is the root directory and that's not where your files are. Additionally you didn't tell make what to build if that's your whole makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the "all" target with object files as dependencies, in order to run the command "make" or "make all".
There are also some mistakes in makefile syntax and on paths. Here are suggestion of solution:

```
SRCS := ./src/server.cpp ./lib/server/server.cpp      # input source files
OBJS := ./build/server/user.o ./build/server/server.o # output object files

# ALL TARGET
all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    g++ ... # to complete to generate object files from source files
```